# Problems retrieving value to a checkbox field in bootstrap modal form while updating the existing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal form for updating the field. The problem is while trying to update the existing data, I can get the value of other fields in the form but not the checkbox field.

Heres jquery:

```
function editSubmit(id){
            var name= $('#name-'+id).text(); #name-id is the id of the <td> field in table
            var work_day = $('#work_day-'+id).text();   #this is checkbox field. I am getting the value 'true' or 'false' in console but not in the form 

            $('#id_name_edit').val(name);     #id_name_edit is the id of the text input in form

            if(work_day == "True"){
                $('#id_work_day_edit').prop("checked", true);

            }
            $('#row-id-store').val(id);   #this stores the id of the data.

            $('#myEditModal').modal('show');
        }
```

Comment: if work_day is a checkbox shouldn't it be $('#work_day-'+id).val() ? which returns the value of that field instead of text() ? which should return nothing - because a checkbox field has no text fragment?

Comment: yes, I agree.but that shouldn't be it or i might be wrong. i am getting the proper true or false value in console while doing `console.log(work_day)` I think I have problem in the if condition but i just cant figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var work_day = $('#work_day-'+id).is(':checked');
```

And you are using comparison based on String values, make sure you convert both sides to same case (LowerCase/UpperCase).

Comment: somehow i only got 'false` with this even for checked attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var work_day = $('#work_day-'+id).val();
```

Comment: this would only give me an empty string. I have the boolean values set to either true or false string. So doing this would only give me an empty string.

Comment: var work_day= $('#work_day-'+id) .checked     you try this...checked method returns true or false according to checkbox is selected or not

Answer (score 0):

var x = $("#work_day-"+id).is(':checked');

Its give you given checkbox checked or not..true or false